# Custom WordPress theme showing index.php items in functions.php page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, web-deployment

I'm following a video tutorial to convert a custom HTML template into a WordPress website. I copied my files into the `themes` folder and have renamed my files properly according to WordPress standards. Whilst I managed to get WordPress recognise my theme through edits in `style.css`, when I launch the website, I got a blank page.

I have an `index.php` filled with my front page code and a blank `functions.php` page. When I visit the the website at `localhost/wordpress/`, I got a blank page. When I open `localhost/wordpress/functions.php`, I got all the stuff.

I've searched online for solutions but still got no luck. I've also tried the debugging code, but I don't see any issue with my PHP code because I only had `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` in my code.

What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename index.php to front-page.php, and leave a blank index.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).